# Passing laravel eloquent query params dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have the following query params in string format

```
$query =  '->whereIn('short_code', ["9999"])->whereBetween('request_timestamp', [request('startTime'), request('endTime')])';
```

How do i pass it to the eloquent? Am trying to achieve something like this

```
InboundMessage::query()->{$query};
```

Am getting the error below

```
Property [->whereIn('short_code', ["9999"])->whereBetween('request_timestamp', [request('startTime'), request('endTime')])] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.
```

Comment: to convert string to php code you will need to use methods like `unserialize`, `enum` or smth. I have never tried such kind of thing but I think that is the only way

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above query is that it looks like this

```
InboundMessage::query()->->whereIn('short_code', ["9999"])..
```

Since you have put `->` in both the query builder and the $query string. So just adjust your $query to

```
$query = 'whereIn('short_code', ["9999"])->whereBetween('request_timestamp', [request('startTime'), request('endTime')])';
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this (not tested) using raw DB expressions:

```
$query = DB::table('tableName')
->whereRaw('columnName IN ["9999"] AND columnName BETWEEN value1 AND value2')
->get();
```